# Uploading CSV File, PHP/MySQL Query

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

i have a .csv file that looks like this...

```
     Name            AC-No.      Time                State        Exception   Operation

Johnny Starks Depp   1220    4/12/2013 12:45:18 AM  Check In        OK   
Johnny Starks Depp   1220    4/12/2013 5:46:58 AM   Out             Out 
Johnny Starks Depp   1220    4/12/2013 6:22:41 AM   Out Back        Out  
Johnny Starks Depp   1220    4/12/2013 10:42:17 AM  Check Out       Repeat   
Johnny Starks Depp   1220    4/12/2013 10:42:19 AM  Check Out       OK
```

i can already upload this to my database. my problem is that, the result it shows in the table.
In mysql database I have a TABLE with columns (**Name, ACNo. , Date, CheckIn, Breakout, Breakin, CheckOut**). What I want to happen that i cannot do right is.. the record/s in the .csv file with the same **DATE** ( which is shown in the TIME Column ) will be in just one same row along with the Check In, BreakOut, BreakIn, and CheckOut in the TABLE and wont result a multiple record.
like this..

```
     Name         |ACNo |     Date  | CheckIn     |  Breakout  |   Breakin  | Checkout
                  |     |           |             |            |            |
Johnny Starks Depp|1220 | 4/12/2013 | 12:45:18 AM | 5:46:58 AM | 6:22:41 AM | 10:42:19 AM
```

Now.. i already did the above example of what i want to happen in the table but... when i check the table, yes it has different dates per row but the time in (CheckIn, Breakout, Breakin, Checkout) are wrong. Wrong, because the time for example in the DATE 4/12/2013 is recorded in the DATE 4/13/2013. What is wrong with the codes i used? Or is there any way else i can do this? these are my codes:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dtrlogs",$conn);

$datehere ="";

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if($file == "")
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('No File Selected!');
    </script>
    <?php
}

else
{
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,";")) !==false)
{
    $Name = $fileop[0];
    $ACNo = $fileop[1];
    $Time = $fileop[2];
    $State = $fileop[3];
    $NewState = $fileop[4];
    $Exception = $fileop[5];
    $Operation = $fileop[6];

    //i separated time/date in the Column TIME in the .csv file
    $date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($Time));
    $hours = date('H:i:s A', strtotime($Time));


    //this is what i used to prevent multiple dates
    if($datehere != $date) {

        $datehere = $date;
    }
    else{

        $date = "";
    }







    //this is to insert the name and acno to the other table. 
    //(this is for the lists of employee)

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee Where ACNo = '$ACNo'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    if($row == 0) {

       $sql1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO employee(ACNo, Name) VALUES('$ACNo','$Name')");
    }



    //Inserts record if Date is not yet recorded and if already has just updates 
    //the row's column (Checkin, breakout, breakin and Checkout) 
    //with its correct time according to the date

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dtrs Where ACNo = '$ACNo' AND Date = '$date'");
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if($rows == 0) {

    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dtrs(Name, ACNo, Date, CheckIn, BreakOut, 
    BreakIn,CheckOut) 
    VALUES('$Name','$ACNo','$date','$CheckIn','$Breakout','$Breakin','$Checkout')");

    }
    else{

    $sql2 = mysql_query("Update dtrs Set CheckIn = '$CheckIn', BreakOut = 
    '$Breakout', BreakIn = '$Breakin', CheckOut = '$Checkout'");
    }







    //this is my conditions to identify whether the TIME/HOUR is 
    //Stated as CheckIn, Breakout, Breakin, or Checkout

    if($NewState == "Check In" || $State == 'Check In' && $Exception == "OK") {

        if($Exception == "Invalid" || $Exception == "Repeat")
        {}
        else {
            $CheckIn = $hours;
        }
    }
    if($State == 'Out' && $Exception == "Out") {

        if($Exception == "Invalid" || $Exception == "Repeat")
        {}
        else {
            $Breakout = $hours;
        }
    }
    if($State == 'Out Back' && $Exception == "Out") {

        if($Exception == "Invalid" || $Exception == "Repeat")
        {}
        else {
            $Breakin = $hours;
        }
    }
    if($NewState == "Check Out" || $State == "Check Out" && $Exception == "OK") {

        if($NewState == "Check In")
        {}
        else {
            $Checkout = $hours;
        }
     }


}


if($sql2)
{
if($sql2)
{


?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('File Upload Successful!');
    </script>
<?php
}
}
}

}

?>
```

Comment: what is the query returning on insert? i mean what kind of values are in $CheckIn, $Breakout, $Breakin, $CheckOut and where are they declared? maybe that's the problem.

Also one good tip, when something doesn't insert update or select from db, debug the string query which you are sending :)

Comment: Duplicate of [.csv file upload to database using php/mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711240/csv-file-upload-to-database-using-php-mysql)

Comment: the values in the variables($CheckIn, $Breakout, $Breakin, $CheckOut) are in the IF Conditions. this IF will identify whether the the $Hour's value is Stated as one of the 4(CheckIn, out, outback, CheckOut). you get what i mean? if the Value in $Hour is Stated as "Check In", the value in $Hour will be put in the $CheckIn. and will loop again and go back to the conditions.

anyways, what do you mean about "Also one good tip, when something doesn't insert update or select from db, debug the string query which you are sending :)"? i didnt get what youre telling me. sorry bout that XD

Comment: @Steve you said that the time inserted is wrong, can you tell me the datetime difference between values in csv and the database for each columns (CheckIn, out, outback, checkOut). Are they all have same time difference? if Yes, it's probably because the TimeZone setting in your local server

Comment: @dArc okay. sorry about that. while i was debugging i found out that all the **TIME** in my .csv file is upload **BUT** some of the **time** is not in the correct row w/ its right date or where it should belong. i think the problem now is how the csv uploader uploads the file in the database **OR** it is my IF condition, causing of not properly arranged table data inserted.

Comment: @dArc i really dont know what else to code or to change in here. im really getting very confused about it. I cant figure out what really causes the dis arrangement of the data inside the table.

Comment: @CBroe not really a Duplicate, i changed the codes and i figured out something about my first problem. and i still have another one. so i posted this again. sorry if i dont know really know how to use this Q&A site. just signed up yesterday.

Comment: in your `UPDATE` query, you should put `WHERE Name='$Name' AND ACNo='$ACNO'`

Comment: @dArc it's still have the same result. maybe that was not it, maybe it is how i put condition on the **DATE**? I have so many IFs. im really confused now. i even changed other statements, still nothing and results are the same. but thanks for that. :(

Comment: by the way @Steve, you should SET The variables value (the IF statement) on top of the `insert or update` queries.

Comment: thanks @dArc ! i have solved some of the problems about the TIME and DATE disarrangement. some of your suggestions helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest possibly loading to a transient table, and from that extracting the details to use to populate your real table.

For example, if you loaded you CSV file to a table called LoadTable (not a temp table, as you can only use a temp table once in a piece of SQL), you could extract the distinct name and account number, then join that against subselects to get the max event times for each of the relevant events.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT DerivMain.Name, 
    DerivMain.ACNo, 
    DerivMain.EventDate, 
    DATE_FORMAT(DerivCheckIn.EventDateTime, '%l:%i:%s %p'), 
    DATE_FORMAT(DerivBreakout.EventDateTime, '%l:%i:%s %p'),  
    DATE_FORMAT(DerivBreakin.EventDateTime, '%l:%i:%s %p'), 
    DATE_FORMAT(DerivCheckout.EventDateTime, '%l:%i:%s %p')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name, ACNo, DATE(STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p')) As EventDate FROM LoadTable) DerivMain
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Name, ACNo, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p') AS EventDateTime) FROM LoadTable WHERE State = 'Check In' GROUP BY Name, ACNo) DerivCheckIn
ON DerivMain.Name = DerivCheckIn Name AND DerivMain.ACNo = DerivCheckIn.ACNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Name, ACNo, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p') AS EventDateTime) FROM LoadTable WHERE State = 'Out' GROUP BY Name, ACNo) DerivBreakout
ON DerivMain.Name = DerivBreakout Name AND DerivMain.ACNo = DerivBreakout.ACNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Name, ACNo, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p') AS EventDateTime) FROM LoadTable WHERE State = 'Out Back' GROUP BY Name, ACNo) DerivBreakin
ON DerivMain.Name = DerivBreakin Name AND DerivMain.ACNo = DerivBreakin.ACNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Name, ACNo, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p') AS EventDateTime) FROM LoadTable WHERE State = 'Check Out' GROUP BY Name, ACNo) DerivCheckout
ON DerivMain.Name = DerivCheckout Name AND DerivMain.ACNo = DerivCheckout.ACNo
```

Comment: thanks kickstart. but i dont know how to use that code. im not really familiar in JOINs and its so hard to understand. what does transients really do? i searched about it but it seems i find it hard to understand what it do. thank you for the effort on solving this. much appreciated

Comment: By transient table I don't mean a special type of table, I just mean set up a table (normal table) to use while doing the loading, then delete it once you have finished with it. Once it is loaded in that table (I have just called it LoadTable in the above) you can manipulate it relatively easily. That SQL above has subselects each of which get the latest date / time for one event for each name / acno. These are then joined together to get you a row with the values in it the output you need